# Extract person from an image or make the background transparent

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to extract the person in a image without any background.I want to do this for multiple images of the same kind.Please help me do so using python which can automate this process.

https://depositphotos.com/148319285/stock-video-man-run-on-green-screen.html
I,ve tried using canny edge detector could only find edges but couldnot crop it.Is there any alternative way to detect background and remove completely.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988559/selecting-colors-from-an-image-with-opencv-and-mask/53989391#53989391) about selecting a green area. Invert the mask and you select everything exept the green. Do this for every frame as described [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Answer (score 0):

Background subtraction using opencv. Check the link for examples and details: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html

Comment: This examples are for videos i would like to have only the person from the image as my output

Comment: Sorry for sharing the video.Assume it as a image

Answer (score 0):

In case of such prepared images, you migth find useful simple thresholding: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html in your case you would need to get grayscale image by extracting green channel from image. It would produce binary (black and white ONLY) image with white for background and black for object (or reverse depending on your choice).

Comment: I want to extract the person from the image thresholding doesn't help me to do so